# How do I plot $x^2+y^2=1$ in 3D?

Tags: plotting

How would I plot $x^2+y^2=1$ in 3D (it would form a cylinder)? Since there is no $z$ in the equation, I can't solve for it and use `Plot3D`. Or can I just put the equation into Plot3D? I am very new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about a 3D contour plot.

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: Oh, great! Thanks!

Comment: No problem!  Have fun Ben.

Answer (score 11):

Although Mark's answer is the "natural" one, here are other options just for completeness:

Use Plot3D, after performing a rotation:

```
Plot3D[{1, -1} Sqrt[1 - x x], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `ParametricPlot3D[]`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{1, -1, 1} #, {1, 1, 1} #} &@{x, Sqrt[1 - x x], z}, {x, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `RevolutionPlot3D[]` after realizing for example that in the semi/plane `{y==0, x>0}` x takes only the value `1` and `z` takes any value (freely):

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{1, t}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yet another possibility: `ParametricPlot3D[RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}][{1, 0, r}] // Evaluate, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]`

Comment: Man, thanks so much for this. This is great.