# How to make a 3D plot of $(x^2+y^2-1)^2+(y^2+z^2-1)^2+(x^2+z^2-1)^2=0$

Tags: plotting

How can I make a 3D plot of

$$(x^2+y^2-1)^2+(y^2+z^2-1)^2+(x^2+z^2-1)^2=0$$

Does the above equation describes the same region as

$$x^2+y^2\le 1\wedge y^2+z^2\le 1\wedge x^2+z^2\le 1$$

Comment: Do we have a canonical version that this one can be marked a duplicate of?  I thought we did but I cannot find it.  The problem is that it's not that obvious to a newbie how to get from *implicit equation* (usual math term) to `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Here are a couple of candidates. 3D: [10710](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10710/how-do-i-plot-x2y2-1-in-3d). 2D: [34668](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34668/how-can-i-plot-implicit-equations).  But since this solution set is a finite set of points (one might call it a degenerate surface), using `ContourPlot3D` is not a solution.  See [ubpdqn's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1997/ubpdqn) answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right, I wasn't careful.

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually the OP's second formulation is the intersection of three solid cylinders, which is quite different.  (This time, I was careless.  I didn't even read it the first time.)

Comment: @UnitedKingdom Since the second region is bounded by cylinders, you can get a good plot with `ParametricPlot3D` like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/hEL0u.png.  Code dump here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21045469#21045469

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ContourPlot3D` seems to do it

```
f = (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^2 + (y^2 + z^2 - 1)^2 + (x^2 + z^2 - 1)^2;
ContourPlot3D[f, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[1], Mesh -> None, Contours -> {1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are many other options you can try for this command.  You can change the options for `Contours` `Opacity`, and `Mesh`, etc.

#### Update

Answer for comment:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x^2 + z^2 <= 1, 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks,maybe is $x^2+y^2\le 1,y^2+z^2\le 1,x^2+z^2\le 1$

Comment: @UnitedKingdom I updated the answer for your comment reply

Comment: It's very nice,Thank you

Comment: Why do you set contours at 1, when the equation in OP requires 0?

Answer (score 21):

$(x^2+y^2-1)^2+(y^2+z^2-1)^2+(x^2+z^2-1)^2=0$

is satisfied by a set of points. This can be established:

```
f = (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^2 + (y^2 + z^2 - 1)^2 + (x^2 + z^2 - 1)^2;
FullSimplify[Reduce[f == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]]
Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 1 && z^2 + y^2 == 1 && x^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}]
```

i.e.

```
(x == -(1/Sqrt[2]) || x == 1/Sqrt[2]) && (y == -(1/Sqrt[2]) || 
   y == 1/Sqrt[2]) && (z == -(1/Sqrt[2]) || z == 1/Sqrt[2])
```

Note as expected the last 2 results are equivalent. f=0, is a set of 8 points (vertices of a cube). This is separate issue for surfaces of f=n that can be explored by `ContourPlot3D`.

This can be seen in many ways:

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[
  x^2 + y^2 == 1 && z^2 + y^2 == 1 && x^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}];
dr = DiscretizeRegion[ir]
```

[image]

This can be visualised by using `ContourPLot3D` (as alluded to by Nasser ) imagine the limiting process to contour value 0:

```
ContourPlot3D[f, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
 Contours -> {0.1, 0.2, 0.4}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.2], Opacity[0.2], Opacity[0.2]}, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Just another way to see this:

```
pts = Tuples[{-1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, 3];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 1], 
  Cylinder[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1],
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, Sqrt[3/2]],
  Opacity[1], PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[pts]}, Boxed -> False, 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]