# How to plot an ellipsoid from an implicit equation

Tags: plotting

I need a way to plot a generic ellipsoid given the following implicit equation. Can someone help me?

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

Comment: Look up `ContourPlot3D[]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10710/how-do-i-plot-x2y2-1-in-3d.  2D version: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34668/how-can-i-plot-implicit-equations

Comment: Is the problem plotting a surface defined by an equation, or is it something else, such as what to do about the literal constants, `a`, `b`, `c`?  Please clarify.

Comment: @AndreaLeo if your question relates how to plot this using Mathematica, there are a number of ways and some useful suggestions and links have been provided. This site is very willing to help if you have difficulties with your attempts beyond just requesting "how do you...?" I will post some options as answer but in future please try for yourself. You will have fun, learn things and if you get stuck people will be willing and able to assist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See my general comment. Note [`Ellipsoid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html) is a built-in function.

Here are some ways you could do this:

```
e[a_, b_, c_] := 
 ContourPlot3D[
  x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2, {x, -1.1 a, 1.1 a}, {y, -1.1 b, 
   1.1 b}, {z, -1.1 c, 1.1 c}, Contours -> {1}, 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, 
  Background -> Black, Axes -> False]
p[a_, b_, c_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{a Sin[u] Cos[v], b Sin[u] Sin[v], c Cos[u]}, {u, 0,
    Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> False, Background -> Black, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
s[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Graphics3D[
  GeometricTransformation[Sphere[], ScalingTransform[{a, b, c}]], 
  Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
el[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}], Background -> Black, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

Showing:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{e[a, b, c], p[a, b, c]}, {s[a, b, c], el[a, b, c]}}], {a, 1, 
  5}, {b, 1, 5}, {c, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a wonderful page on **Wolfram MathWorld**: [`Ellipsoid`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid.html) where you can also download a `NB`.

There are two good friends; [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) and [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html?q=RegionPlot3D);

```
a = 3; b = 2; c = 1;
ContourPlot3D[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

```
With[{a = 3, b = 2, c = 1},
 RegionPlot3D[
  x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 < 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1, 1},
   BoxRatios -> Automatic]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: There's also a wonderful page in the documentation: [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html)  ;-)