# how do I 3D Plot f(x,y,z)=0

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am very new to mathematica and was wondering how I could 3Dplot -5(x-2)-7y+3(z+4)=0 I've tried 3DPlot and Contour but neither have seemed to work.
PLease help.

Comment: Look up `ContourPlot3D[]`.

Comment: @J.M. it is 2D case but I think it is good enough to be a duplicate, what do you think? [How can I plot implicit equations?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34668/5478)

Comment: @Kuba, let's leave it open for now until somebody finds an actual dupe. I have the feeling closing a 3D question as a dupe of a 2D problem is a slippery slope.

Comment: @J.M. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10710/5478?

Comment: for some reason the ContourPlot3D doesn't seem to work on my mathematica

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* do you have? (Please edit your question to include this information.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)

Plotting a Function see [Function Visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionVisualization.html),

```
ContourPlot3D[-5 (x - 2) - 7 y + 3 (z + 4) == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Adding a plan `z` an `y`,

```
cp1 = ContourPlot3D[{-5 (x - 2) - 7 y + 3 (z + 4) == 0, z, y}
, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}
, ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

[image]

Solve for Intersections,

```
Solve[{-5 (x - 2) - 7 y + 3 (z + 4) == 0 && z == 0 && y == 0, z == 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

> {{x->22/5,y->0,z->0}}

And Visualise the whole gang:

```
Show[cp1, Graphics3D[{White, Sphere[{22/5, 0, 0}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: first solve with respect to z:

```
sl = Solve[-5 (x - 2) - 7 y + 3 (z + 4) == 0, z]

(*  {{z -> 1/3 (-22 + 5 x + 7 y)}}  *)
```

Then plot it in 3D:

```
Plot3D[sl[[1, 1, 2]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Have fun!