# Draw two planes of Cartesian equation: y=3-x and z=2+x with Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I have two Cartesian equation of plans: `y=3-x` and `z=2+x`.
I want to draw both planes with `Plot3D` but I don't know what I have to put in the fonction.

Comment: This link could be useful: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~hurley/math220/Mathematica_docs/Planes.pdf

Comment: Look up `ContourPlot3D[]` in the documentation.

Comment: Duplicates: [(10710)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10710), [(116573)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116573)

Comment: I rather wish it could be marked a duplicate of both...The first is almost general enough, but the later question seems a closer duplicate, especially by virtue of its answers.

Answer (score 1):

`Plot3D` plots $f(x,y)$ as a function of $(x,y)$. The second plane, $z=2+x$ can be plotted with

```
Plot3D[2 + x, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

The first plane, $f(x,y)=x+y-3\equiv 0$, so it won't work. But `ContourPlot3D` works for any plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$:

```
ContourPlot3D[{y == 3 - x, z == 2 + x}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

See also [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34038/plot-points-line-and-plane-in-one-3d-plot).